# Should I use utf8_decode when returning db results stored as utf8_general_ci and/or utf8_unicode_ci?

Tags: php, mysql

Should I use `utf8_decode` when returning db results stored as `utf8_general_ci` and/or `utf8_unicode_ci`, or is it simply a case of making sure the file encoding, HTML content-type and db storage all match up?

Comment: Both could be valid, if you _want_ to deliver iso-8859-15 for instance, you'd convert the lot, if you want to deliver utf-8 no decoding would be necessary (but you should send proper utf-8 headers). There is no specific need for everything to match up as long as you are aware what character set something is at any stage, and conduct proper conversions, but of course it does help to just employ 1 encoding and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy,

I think it's no need to use any decode, just to have the:

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

in your php script, and

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

in the html page.